# Missing write access error on nativescript install

Tags: npm, nativescript, node-modules

When I attempt to install nativescrtipt by running `npm i -g nativescript`, I receive the following error:

```
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to 
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall access
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a 
    file.
```

I have tried to run the command as sudo and receive the same result.  I also attempted to add write permission to the `node_modules` directory.

I am running node v10.6.0 on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Did the tips specific to Mac mentioned here help  - https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` and then install nativescript

Answer (score 6):

Add `sudo` command to allow you run the program with security privilege

```
sudo npm i -g nativescript
```

Comment: Adding package using sudo will be problem when you run main program without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally to resolve the issue.

I installed nvm and updated to the latest version of node.  Then, the command `npm i -g nativescript` successfully installed the nativescript-cli.

The issue does not appear to be coming from nativescript, but an issue with my node installation.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command `sudo npm i -g nativescript`

This will forcefully with security permission install the missing scripts to run the npm command again with no bugs or warnings

Comment: This is a late re-answer of an already (identical answer) @GDSKS.  If you can add something extra relevant (that overcomes the issues that were raised with the original answer then please do).